# Is this function multiplicative and if so what is its value at prime powers?

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, multiplicative-function

For odd numbers $n$ let:

$$a(n) = \sum_{d^2|n} d \frac{\sigma^*(n/d^2)}{2^{\omega(n/d^2)}}$$

where $\sigma^*(k) = $ sum of unitary ($\gcd(d,k/d)=1$) divisors of $k$ and $\omega$ counts the prime divisors.

Is this function multiplicative for odd numbers, and if so what is its value at odd prime powers?

**Edit**:
Sorry for not giving any context when asking the question, which I will do now:

Let $n$ be a natural number. Let $U_n = \{d \in \mathbb{N}| d|n \text{ and } \gcd(d,n/d)=1 \}$ be the set of unitary divisors, $D_n$ be the set of divisors and $S_n=\{d \in \mathbb{N}|d^2 | n\}$ be the set of square divisors of $n$.

The set $U_n$ is a group with $a\oplus b  := \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2}$. It operates on $D_n$ via:

$$ u \oplus d := \frac{ud}{\gcd(u,d)^2}$$

The orbits of this operation "seem" to be

$$ U_n \oplus d = d \cdot U_{\frac{n}{d^2}} \text{ for each } d \in S_n$$

From this conjecture it follows (also one can prove this directly since both sides are multiplicative and equal on prime powers):

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{d\in S_n} d\sigma^*(\frac{n}{d^2})$$

where $\sigma^*$ denotes the sum of unitary divisors.

Since $\sigma^*(k)$ is divisible by $2^{\omega(k)}$ if $k$ is odd, where $\omega=$ counts the number of distinct prime divisors of $k$, for an odd perfect number $n$ we get (Let now $n$ be an odd perfect number):

$$2n = \sigma(n) = \sum_{d \in S_n} d \sigma^*(\frac{n}{d^2}) = \sum_{d \in S_n} d 2^{\omega(n/d^2)} k_d $$

where $k_d = \frac{\sigma^*(n/d^2)}{2^{\omega(n/d^2)}}$ are natural numbers.
Let $\hat{d}$ be the largest square divisor of $n$. Then:
$\omega(n/d^2)\ge \omega(n/\hat{d}^2)$.

Hence we get:

$$2n = 2^{\omega(n/\hat{d}^2)} \sum_{d \in S_n} d l_d$$
for some natural numbers $l_d$.

If the prime $2$ divides not the prime power $2^{\omega(n/\hat{d}^2})$, we must have $\omega(n/\hat{d}^2)=0$ hence $n=\hat{d}^2$ is a square number, which is in contradiction to Eulers theorem on odd perfect numbers.

So the prime $2$ must divide the prime power $2^{\omega(n/\hat{d}^2})$ and we get:

$$n = 2^{\omega(n/\hat{d}^2)-1} \sum_{d \in S_n} d l_d$$

with $l_d = \frac{\sigma^*(n/d^2)}{2^{\omega(n/d^2)}}$. Hence the odd perfect number, satisifies:

$$n = \sum_{d^2|n} d \frac{\sigma^*(n/d^2)}{2^{\omega(n/d^2)}}=a(n)$$

Hence an odd perfect number satisifies:

$$n = a(n)$$

So my idea was to study the function on the right hand side and what properties it has to maybe derive insights into odd perfect numbers.

**The real question is if it ever can happen that an odd number $n$ satisfies: $n=a(n)$?** (checked for $n=2k+1$ and $1 \le k \le 10^7$)

Comment: Yes, it is multiplicative for odd numbers. How did you come up with this function?

Comment: @Somos: I updated the question with some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $a(n)$ is multiplicative. If we define
\begin{align*}
f(m) &= \begin{cases}
\sqrt m, &\text{if $m$ is a perfect square}, \\ 0, &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases} \\
g(m) &= \frac{\sigma^*(m)}{2^{\omega(m)}},
\end{align*}
then it's reasonably easy to see that both $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative functions and that
$$
a(n) = \sum_{k\mid n} f(k) g(n/k).
$$
In other words $a=f*g$ is a Dirichlet convolution of two multiplicative functions and is therefore multiplicative. Its value at the prime power $p^j$ is
$$
\sum_{d^2\mid p^j} d \frac{\sigma^*(n/d^2)}{2^{\omega(n/d^2)}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor} p^i \frac{\sigma^*(p^{j-2i})}{2^{\omega(p^{j-2i})}}.
$$
If $j$ is odd then this is
$$
\frac12 \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor} p^i \sigma^*(p^{j-2i}) = \frac12 \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor} p^i (p^{j-2i}+1) = \frac12\sum_{i=0}^{(j-1)/2} (p^{j-i}+p^i),
$$
which can be evaluated via finite geometric series; a similar calculation will cover the case where $j$ is even (careful with the $2^\omega$ term when $i=\frac j2$).

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin for your answer! I did a similar calculation and come to the same result.